# Way to get output if PLY parser did not find syntax error

Tags: python, ply

I wrote a very simple first-order logic parser using Ply in Python (I'm very new to both). I managed to use the official example provided so that when there is a syntax error, it prints that there is a syntax error. However, I would like it to print something when there is no syntax error, i.e. when the formula put in is syntactically correct.

Is there any way to do this? I haven't found anything in the official documentation.

Comment: Could you share the coding, that you tried. Along with any error message you encountered, and probably also this "official example provided"

Comment: Sure, the official example provided can be accessed on the official website [here](https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/example.html)

The relevant end of my code (given the length limits of comments) is the following, but it really doesn't include any 'trying', because I have no idea how to even start. It's almost identical to the example given. 

`while True:
    s = input('Write something bro: ')
    parser.parse(s)

input()`